# Bootstrap 3 container-fluid with offset

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a col of 1170px width inside of an container-fluid.

This

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <h2>Container-Fluid with Offset</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

is not the same as this

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Container</h2>
</div>
```

[image]

Whats the best way to get the width of 1170px inside of an container-fluid ?

Comment: If you want a width of 1170px, then it isnt a fluid container. Why not just use container?

Comment: because I need a different background color

Answer (score 0):

container-fluid is full width container. It means it has not margin or padding.

You need to notice bootstrap structure is **container>row>column**
A main reason to follow this is "hooking rule" for browser support keeping the visual structure. Or you will experience "bugs" for old browsers.

If you want full width column you include a column of 12 or similar if you include offsets. 12 is the max num of columns per row. Give a look to [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

```css
.myclass {
background:#ffcc00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xs-12 myclass">
    PEACE IN THE WORLD
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

If you want specific width column you can use a custom div inside your row also. Bootstrap columns are relatively sized.

```css
.myclass {

width:1170px;
background:#ffcc00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="myclass">
    PEACE IN THE WORLD
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```